# Collect string from multiple Word files and store it in dataframe in order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to collect information from multiple Word files , that are stored in a different folders and sub folders.
With the script below I don`t get the full information and when I try to extract data from old word format –“ .doc ” it’s giving me an error that it’s not word format.

```
import glob
import os
import re
import docx



with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for directory in glob.glob('*'):
        for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*")):
            if filename.endswith((".docx")):
                document = docx.Document(filename)
                for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
                    if paragraph.text:
                        #docText.append(paragraph.text)
                        f.write(paragraph.text)
```

Folders with Word data/there is sub-folders/:

[image]

Regex is not working on the paragraph.text and I tried to extract the information in a text file and then to get the information.I need to collect in a dataframe : Firm name, Deal name, Value, Description.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

raw_data = open('your_file.txt', 'r').read()
FirmName = re.findall(r'Firm name\s*(.*?)\s*Marketing', raw_data, flags=re.DOTALL)
DealName = re.findall(r'Deal name\s*(.*?)\s*Date completed', raw_data, flags=re.DOTALL)
Value = re.findall(r'Date Completed\s*(.*?)\s*Cliet(s) advised', raw_data, flags=re.DOTALL)
Description = re.findall(r'Description\s*(.*?)\s*Deal Name', raw_data, flags=re.DOTALL)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Firm Name', 'Deal Name','Value', 'Description'])
df = df.append({'Firm Name': FirmName, 'Deal Name': DealName, 'Value': Value, 'Description': Description}, ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv(r'dataset.csv', index=False)
```

The problem that I encounter that when I collect the whole information in one text file, regex extract not in order. Every word file has one Firm Name and multiple deals, value and description. The desire output result:
[image]

***Sample .docx output:***   [file](https://easyupload.io/rsiawv)

[image]

Comment: Re: "when I try to extract data from old word format –“ .doc ” it’s giving me an error that it’s not word format..." – does not say that it's not a Word format (because it is) but that the library cannot read it. That is By Design: "You can open any Word 2007 or later file this way (**.doc files from Word 2003 and earlier won’t work**)" from [the documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html)

Comment: My first guess would be that the paragraph you try to get is on one line, so regex won't catch the next line with the data. Could you provide a sample .docx output?

Comment: That's pretty awful to parse if the above output is really aligned like this. Can you provide a "real" file as well?

Comment: sorry. attached a sample file